# Best way to model Customer <--> Address

Tags: sql, database-design, orm, data-modeling

Every `Customer` has a physical address and an optional mailing address.  What is your preferred way to model this?

Option 1. `Customer` has foreign key to `Address`

```
   Customer   (id, phys_address_id, mail_address_id)
   Address    (id, street, city, etc.)
```

Option 2. `Customer` has one-to-many relationship to `Address`, which contains a field
to describe the address type

```
   Customer   (id)
   Address    (id, customer_id, address_type, street, city, etc.)
```

Option 3. Address information is de-normalized and stored in `Customer`

```
   Customer   (id, phys_street, phys_city, etc. mail_street, mail_city, etc.)
```

One of my overriding goals is to simplify the object-relational mappings, so I'm leaning towards the first approach.  What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tend towards  first approach for all the usual reasons of normalisation.  This approach also makes it easier to perform data cleansing on mailing details.

If you are possibly going to allow multiple addresses (mail, residential, etc) or wish to be able to use effective dates, consider this approach

```
   Customer   (id, phys_address_id)
   Cust_address_type (cust_id, mail_address_id, address_type, start_date, end_date)
   Address    (id, street, city, etc.)
```

Comment: why would you separate cust_address_type and address at all? The information contained in both could sit on one table without any issue. I see no benefit to 3 tables when 2 will do.

Comment: Because then you can have 1 or more addresses per customer e.g. billing, delivery, etc.  Also you can easly track history via the date fields.  You can have multiple customers at the same address and treat each as an entity but changing address for one need not affect others.

Comment: Also this model suits very well situations where you have a list of most addresses and assign them (e.g. if you have bought an address list from the post office or similar).  Or where you database is large enough to have most addresses in your region.

Comment: irrelevant. Two tables are needed only. Put a 'type' field in the address and you solve the issue. Doing this still allows for everything else you stated above. You are clearly able to have multiple entries in your cust_address_type table anyway so combing and placing the actual address in it is simple. I can 'possibly' see some value in multiple customers at one address but this is a rare exception. Design for the 95%, not the 5%.

Comment: you are welcome to your opinion.  And I have gained my experience working with the various systems I have worked with over the last few decades.

Comment: The problem with this design is that it assumes there is only one entity type (customers in this case) that needs an address. What if you also have company entity, supplier entity, ...etc. They all can can have Addresses, do you create supplier_address, company_address,...etc?

Why physical_address_id is still part of Customer table but mail_address is in a cross-reference table?

Comment: I was specifically answering the original question.  One system I worked with that had this used this approach in each module to track addresses for a Local Government ERP.  It tracked Rate Payer Address in the in the rates module, property address in that module, etc.  And in the Name and Address module it had the master list of Names and Address.  The Customer ID was the link to a name, the Address ID allowed you to have multiple addresses per entity type.  And it each entity type had the same address there was only entry in the Name and Address module for that address.

Answer (score 7):

One important fact you may need to consider (depending on your problem domain) is that people change addresses, and may want to let you know in advance of their address change; this is certainly true for utility companies, telcos, etc.

In this case you need to have a way to store multiple addresses for the customer with validity dates, so that the address can be set up in advance and automatically switch at the correct point. If this is a requirement, then a variation on (2) is the only sensible way to model it, e.g.

```
Customer (id, ...)
Address (id, customer_id, address_type, valid_from, valid_to)
```

On the other hand, if you don't need to cater for this (and you're sure you won't in the future) then probably (1) is simpler to manage because it's much easier to maintain data integrity as there's no issues with ensuring only one address of the same type exists, and the joins become simpler as they're only on one field.

So either (1) or (2) are fine depending on whether you need house-moves, but I'd steer clear of (3) because you're then repeating the definition of what an address is in the table, and you'll have to add multiple columns if you change what an address looks like. It's possibly slightly more performant, but to be honest when you're dealing with properly indexed joins in a relational database there isn't a lot to be gained, and it's likely to be slower in some scenarios where you *don't* need the address as the record size for a customer will be larger.

Comment: This address table only tied to customer not order address or office address.

Answer (score 6):

We are moving forward with a model like this:

```
Person (id, given_name, family_name, title, suffix, birth_date)
Address (id, culture_id, line1, line2, city, state, zipCode, province, postalCode)
AddressType (id, descriptiveName)
PersonAddress (person_id, address_id, addressType_id, activeDates)
```

Most may consider this excessive.  However, an undeniable common theme amongst the apps we develop is that they will have some of these fundamental entities - People, Organizations, Addresses, Phone Numbers, etc.. - and they all want to combine them in different ways.  So, we're building in some generalization up-front that we are 100% certain we have use cases for.

The Address table will follow a table-per-hierarchy inheritance scheme to differentiate addresses based on culture; so a United States address will have a state and zip field, but Canadian addresses will have a province and postal code.

We use a separate connecting table to "give" a person an address.  This keeps our other entities - Person & Address - free from ties to other entities when our experience is this tends to complicate matters down the road.  It also makes it far simpler to connect Address entities to many other types of entities (People, Organizations, etc.) and with different contextual information associated with the link (like activeDates in my example).

Comment: +1 That is the design I would have posted.  I've used that connecting table to drive a lot of functionality.  Data cleansing even marketing mailers.  It comes in useful when those who want reports can see what customers where mailed to in the last campaign, etc..

Comment: so far this is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

The second option would probably be the way I would go.  And on the off-chance it would let users add additional address' (If you wanted to let them do that), that they could switch between at will for shipping and such.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer #1. Good normalization and communicates intent clearly. This model also allows the *same* address object (row) to be used for both addresses, something I have found to be quite valuable. It's far too easy to get lost in duplicating this information too much.

Comment: I'd be interested in how this was done in the UI. I have built a system that allows address objects to be shared, but users didn't get the concept.

Comment: I think you mean the second one, based on your description.  They're all marked #1

Answer (score 3):

When answering those kinds of questions I like to use the classifications of [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). If it's a Entity it should have a separate ID, if it's a value object it should not.

Answer (score 2):

Option 3 is too restrictive, and option 1 cannot be extended to allow for other address types without changing the schema. 
Option 2 is clearly the most flexible and therefore the best choice.

Comment: I agree that it is the most flexible, but is it worth the trade-off in ORM complexity?

Answer (score 2):

In most code I write nowadays every customer has one and only one physical location. This is the legal entity beeing our business partner. Therefore I put street, city etc in the customer object/table. Often this is the possible simplest thing that works and it works.

When an additional mailing address is needed, I put it in a separate object/table to not clutter the customer object to much.

Earlier in my career I normalized like mad having an order referencing a customer which references a shipping address. This made things "clean" but slow and inelegant to use. Nowadays I use an order object which just contains all the address information. I actually consider this more natural since a customer might change his (default?) address, but the address of a shipment send in 2007 should always stay the same - even if the customer moves in 2008.

We currently implement the [VerySimpleAddressProtocol](http://github.com/hudora/huTools/blob/master/doc/standards/address_protocol.markdown#readme) in out project to standardize the fields used.

Comment: Your point of address data change is invalid. A single address row shall not change, if referenced in entities where it must not change. In case a adress shall change a new record must be created, if it is equal to an existing one, use the existing one. You preserve history. We used this approach in an factoring company and e-commerce product. You can use language dependent rules to clean user input adress data to reach very good comparison quality. Or use external providers like postal companies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the first option. In these situations I'm very weary of YAGNI (you aren't going to need it). I can't count the number of times I've looked at schemas that've had one-to-many tables "just incase" that are many years old. If you only need two, just use the first option; if the requirement changes in the future, change it then.

Answer (score 1):

Like in many cases: **It depends.**

If your customers deal with multiple addresses then a to-many relationship would be appropriate. You could introduce a flag on address that signals if an address is for shipment or bill, etc. Or you store the different address types in different tables and have multiple to-one relationships on a customer.

In cases where you only need to know one address of a customer why would you model that to-many? A to-one relationship would satisfy your needs here.

Important: Denormalize only if you encounter performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1. If you want to, you could even modify it a little bit to keep an address history:

```
Customer   (id, phys_address_id, mail_address_id)
Address    (id, customer_id, start_dt, end_dt, street, city, etc.)
```

If the address changes, just end date the current address and add a new record in the `Address` table. The `phys_address_id` and `mail_address_id` always point to the current address.

That way you can keep a history of addresses, you could have multiple mailing addresses stored in the database (with the default in `mail_address_id`), and if the physical address and mailing address are identical you'll just point `phys_address_id` and `mail_address_id` at the same record.

Comment: -1 - With this design you've got a two-way dependency between the Address and Customer tables, which makes the database schema more brittle, while adding no real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Good thread. I have spent a while contemplating the most suitable schema and I have concluded that quentin-starin's solution is the best except I have added **start_date** and **end_date** fields to what would be his PersonAddress table. I have also decided to add **notes**, **active** and **deleted**.

**deleted** is for soft delete functionality as I think I do not want to lose trace of previous addresses simply by deleting the record from the junction table. I think that is quite wise and something others may want to consider. If not done this way, it could be left to revision of paper or electronic documents to try to trace address information (something best avoided).

**notes** I think of being something of a requirement but that might just be preference. I've spent time in backfill exercises verifying addresses in databases and some addresses can be very vague (such as rural addresses) that I think it is very useful to at least allow notes about that address to be held in the record address.

One thing i would like to hear opinions on is the unique indexing of the **address** table (again, referring to the table of the same name in quentin-starin's example. Do you think it should be unique index should be enforced (as a compound index presumably across all not-null/required fields)? This would seem sensible but it might still be hard to stop duplicate data regardless as postal/zip codes are not always unique to a single property. Even if the country, province and city fields are populated from reference data (which they are in my model), spelling differences in the address lines may not match up. The only way to best avoid this might be to run one or a number of DB queries from the incoming form fields to see if a possible duplicate has been found. Another safety measure would be give the user the option of selecting from address in the database already linked to that person and use that to auto-populate. I think this might be a case where you can only be sensible and take precautions to stop duplication but just accept it can (and probably will) happen sooner or later.

The other very important aspect of this for me is future editing of the **address** table records. Lets say you have 2 people both listed at: -

11 Whatever Street
Whatever City
Z1P C0D3

Should it not be considered dangerous to allow the same **address** table record to be assigned to different entities (person, company)? Then let's say the user realises one of these people lives at 111 Whatever Street and there is a typo. If you change that address, it will change it for both of the entities. I would like to avoid that. My suggestion would be to have the model in the MVC (in my case, PHP Yii2) look for existing **address** records when a new address is being created known to be related to that customer (SELECT * FROM address INNER JOIN personaddress ON personaddress.address_id = address.id WHERE personaddress.person_id = {current person being edited ID}) and provide the user the option of using that record instead (as was essentially suggested above).

I feel linking the same address to multiple different entities is just asking for trouble as it might be a case of refusing later editing of the **address** record (impractical) or risking that the future editing of the record may corrupt data related to other entities outside of the one who's **address** record is being edited.

I would love to hear people's thoughts.