# How to give an order a shipping address and a billing address in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, modeling

In my online store, each order is associated with a shipping address and a billing address (they can be the same, of course). This is my first attempt to model this:

```
Class Order
  belongs_to :billing_address, :class => "Address"
  belongs_to :shipping_address, :class => "Address"
```

This works pretty well, but now the form helpers don't work. I.e., `form_for` will only generate fields with names like `address[zipcode]`, so I have to manually hack it to get `billing_address[zipcode]` and `shipping_address[zipcode]`.

I guess I could use single table inheritance to subclass `Address` into `ShippingAddress` and `BillingAddress`, but this seems a bit hacky to me (and contradicts some good answers in [Best way to model Customer <--> Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648463/best-way-to-model-customer-address)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two ideas for you, either or both of which may do the trick:

```
Class Order
  belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address"
  belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address"

Class Order
  belongs_to :address, :foreign_key => "billing_address_id"
  belongs_to :address, :foreign_key => "shipping_address_id"
```

Please give them a try with your form helpers and I'd be interested to know if it works out for you.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the class name, since it's not BillingAddress or ShippingAddress.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # foreign key not required here because it will look for
  # association_name_id, e.g. billing_address_id, shipping_address_id
  belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address"
  belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address"
end
```

To complete the association:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # foreign key required here because it will look for class_name_id, 
  # e.g. address_id
  has_many :billing_orders, :class_name => "Order", 
    :foreign_key => "billing_address_id" 
  has_many :shipping_orders, :class_name => "Order", 
    :foreign_key => "shipping_address_id"
end
```

Comment: Does it not make more sense for an Address to belong to an Order?